# How to convert SQL query with subquery to Doctrine QueryBuilder format?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to transcribe this sql statement to doctrine format. It was complicated because I don't know how to perform subqueries.
The sentence is as follows:

`SELECT * FROM articulo WHERE descripcion = (SELECT descripcion FROM articulo WHERE codigo LIKE 4060981104537)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

```
$codigo = '4060981104537';
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a2')
           ->select('a2.descripcion')
           ->where('a2.codigo LIKE :codigo')
           ->setParameter('codigo', $codigo);

$descripcion =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult();   
   
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
           ->where('m.descripcion= :descripcion')
           ->setParameter('descripcion', $descripcion);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Doctrine expression API for subqueries.
Example for your query:

*you should put following code to Doctrine repository of your **articulo** entity*

```
$codigo = '4060981104537';
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

$qb->where(
  $qb->expr()->in(
    'a.descripcion',
     $this->createQueryBuilder('a2')
       ->select('a2.descripcion')
       ->where('a2.codigo LIKE :codigo')
       ->setParameter('codigo', $codigo)
       ->getDQL()
     )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do sth like this:

```php
$codigo = 4060981104537;
$expr = $em->getExpressionBuilder();
$em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('*')
   ->from('articulo')
   ->where(
       $expr->in(
           'articulo.descripcion',
           $em->createQueryBuilder()
               ->select('*')
               ->from('articulo', 'secondArticulo')
               ->where('secondArticulo.codigo LIKE :codigo')
               )
               ->getDQL()
       )
   )
   ->setParameter('codigo', $codigo);
```

And for more info look at this [link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#subqueries)

Comment: It still doesn't work, I don't know why 

Comment: what is the problem? do you get any error?

Comment: just when I try to make it work it returns an error: 
"DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"